# Installing MATLAB Runtime on CentOS 7

Tags: centos, matlab-compiler

I am trying to install the MATLAB Runtime (see www.mathworks.com/products/compiler/mcr) on Cent0S 7.   I think I have installed MCR correctly because the install finishes through saying it completed after running

sudo ./install -mode silent -agreeToLicense yes

However, I am currently getting a error of:

```
    Fatal error loading library /usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Compiler_Runtime/v80/bin/glnxa64/libmwmclmcr.so Error: libXmu.so.6: cannot open shared object file
```

I have searched around on the forums and found a couple of post that indicate this may be an issue with either 32-bit vs. 64-bit libraries and/or X Windows.  Also, I am pretty sure I am setting the following environment LD_LIBRARY_PATH and XAPPLRESDIR set variables correctly.

Has anyone out there successfully installed MATLAB Runtime on CentOS 7? Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks, 
Derek

Answer (score 4):

In case anyone else has this issue the following library install fixed the issue for me:

```
    sudo yum install libXmu.x86_64
```